# How to use the value of an input to render specific content on the same page without a page refresh or a form submit in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, forms

I am trying to build a student catalog. I have a structure which consists in Classes -> Groups -> Students.
I already have the classes and groups in my database. Each group belongs to a class.
As an example, I go to my Class page and I create class 1. After this, I go to my group page and add a group "A" that has class 1 assigned to it. I can add multiple groups to each class.
Now I want to create a student on my student page. To do this, I want to add the student in a specific group. To be able to chose the group, the admin has to firstly select the class from a select dropdown. After the class gets selected, the next select will render only the groups assigned to the selected class.

My solution for this right now is to set the $_GET super global with the class id that was selected by the user in the first dropdown. I do this via javascript function with window.location.href url change. I set the logic of the group dropdown to look for the $_GET variable before it renders the options.
I don't think this is a clean and good approach as the page is always refreshed when the location is reset and the input values are always reset.

I just want to use whatever the user has selected from the classes dropdown to render the options in the group dropdown. Is there anything that Laravel 8 built in features can do for me regarding this issue?

As a sample of what I am doing right now:

```
                    <select name="classes" id="classes" onchange="getClassID()"> // getClassID just changes the location and adds the selected class id to the url as a query string
                            @php
                                foreach ($classes as $class) {
                                   if(isset($_GET['classID'])){
                                       if($_GET['classID']*1 === $class->id){
                                       echo " <option value={$class->id} selected>{$class->classes_number}</option>";
                                       } else {
                                     echo " <option value={$class->id}>{$class->classes_number}</option>";
                                     }
                                   } else {
                                     echo " <option value={$class->id}>{$class->classes_number}</option>";
                                   }
                                }
                            @endphp

                    </select>


                       <script>
                            function getClassID(){ //this is called whenever the user changes any class in order to get his input and render the options from the below select 
                                let option = document.getElementById("classes").value;
                                window.location.href='/students/create?classID=' + option;
                            }
                        </script>


                  <select name="group_id" id="group">
                        @php
                                // If the user has changed the initial classes select dropdown value, we will
                                // get all of the groups that have the class that was selected and display them
                                // as options in this select
                                if(isset($_GET['classID'])){
                                    $classID = $_GET['classID']*1;
                                    foreach ($groups as $group) {
                                        if ($group->classes_id === $classID) {
                                           echo "<option value={$group->id}>{$group->group_name}</option>";
                                        }
                                  }
                                }
       
                     else {//another code that handles the situation in which all classes are erased}
                          @endphp
                    </select>
```

Images with my form when the user selects different classes and the groups are rendered differently for each selected class:[image]

[image]

Comment: You would either have to go with something like react or vue. Or something that easier to merge into blade livewire

Comment: Just as a general note, if you're using `@php` you're probably doing something wrong. If you're accessing variables like `$_GET` from a template (or anywhere in Laravel) you're definitely not doing things the right way. Your controller should be doing all the logic (using `Request` objects, not PHP superglobals) and the view should be limited only to displaying things.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the page, you can get the options via api and create the second select on client-side.

```
var groupIdSelect = document.getElementById('group');
function getClassID(){ //this is called whenever the user changes any class in order to get his input and render the options from the below select 
    let classID = document.getElementById("classes").value;
    fetch('api/students/create?classID=' + classID)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((groups) => {
            for (group of groups) {
                if (group.classes_id === classID) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = group.id
                    option.textContent = group.group_name;
                    groupIdSelect.appendChild(option);
                }
            }
        })
}
```